# How to extract the overlapping hospitalization periods in each hospital?

Tags: r, overlapping

There are five variables in df: studyid, hospitalname, Date1, Date2, and group. For each name in hospitalname in df, I would like to extract all combinations where the period from Date1 to Date2 overlaps between groups with group of 0 and 1.

```
library(zoo)

# create example data
df <- data.frame(
  studyid = 1:5,
  Date1 = as.yearmon(c("2020-01", "2020-03", "2020-10", "2020-07", "2020-06")),
  Date2 = as.yearmon(c("2020-02", "2020-10", "2021-02", "2020-08", "2020-10")),
  hospitalname = c("Hospital A", "Hospital A", "Hospital A", "Hospital B", "Hospital B"),
  group = c(0, 1, 0, 1, 0)
)
```

After the analysis, I would like to have the result like this

```
result <- data.frame(
  studyid.0 = c("3","5"),
  Date1_0 = as.yearmon(c("2020-10", "2020-06")),
  Date2_0 = as.yearmon(c("2021-02", "2020-10")),
  studyid.1 = c("2","4"),
  Date1_1 = as.yearmon(c("2020-03", "2020-07")),
  Date2_1 = as.yearmon(c("2020-10", "2020-08")),
  hospitalname = c("Hospital A", "Hospital B")
)
```

I truly appreciate your support.

Answer (score 1):

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)

result <- df %>%
      inner_join(df, by = "hospitalname") %>%
      filter(group.x == 0, group.y == 1,
             Date1.x <= Date2.y, Date1.y <= Date2.x) %>%
      select(studyid.0 = studyid.x, Date1_0 = Date1.x, Date2_0 = Date2.x,
             studyid.1 = studyid.y, Date1_1 = Date1.y, Date2_1 = Date2.y,
             hospitalname) %>%
      distinct()


result
  studyid.0  Date1_0  Date2_0 studyid.1  Date1_1  Date2_1 hospitalname
1         3 Oct 2020 Feb 2021         2 Mar 2020 Oct 2020   Hospital A
2         5 Jun 2020 Oct 2020         4 Jul 2020 Aug 2020   Hospital B
```

The **inner_join()** function creates combinations of rows with the same hospital name. Next, using **filter()** function you can choose rows where the date periods overlap between groups with group of 0 and 1. Then, using **select()** function renames the columns to match your desired output. Finally, the **distinct()** function removes duplicated rows created by the join function.

Alternatively, as was mentioned by @onyambu, you can add ' **suffix = c('_0', '_1')** ' within the inner_join() function instead of using select():

```
result <- df %>%
  inner_join(df, by = "hospitalname", suffix = c("_0", "_1")) %>%
  filter(group_0 == 0, group_1 == 1,
         Date1_0 <= Date2_1, Date1_1 <= Date2_0) %>%
  distinct()
```

This 'suffix' means that all columns with the same name will be suffixed with '_0' for the first data frame and '_1' for the second data frame.

Comment: instead of the long `select line` have `suffix = c('_0', '_1')` within the `inne_join` function

Answer (score 0):

```
   df %>%
     mutate(id=cumsum(group)) %>%
     pivot_wider(id_cols = c(id, hospitalname), names_from = group, 
                  values_from = studyid:Date2, names_vary = 'slowest') %>%
     drop_na()

# A tibble: 2 × 8
     id hospitalname studyid_0 Date1_0   Date2_0   studyid_1 Date1_1   Date2_1  
  <dbl> <chr>            <int> <yearmon> <yearmon>     <int> <yearmon> <yearmon>
1     1 Hospital A           3 Oct 2020  Feb 2021          2 Mar 2020  Oct 2020 
2     2 Hospital B           5 Jun 2020  Oct 2020          4 Jul 2020  Aug 2020
```